# IOS 10 core data executeFetchRequest crashes if called before insertNewObjectForEntityForName

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a strange issue with an app that works perfectly on iOS <10.

After having updated the phone to iOS 10, my app crashes when doing a `executeFetchRequest` before `insertNewObjectForEntityForName`.

It seems to be mostly iPhone6 and up that have the problem (have been told that iPhone5 is ok).

It is crashing at this line in the code below:

```
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

[xcode error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1fmX.jpg)
These methods gives me a headache in 'Scada' class:

```
+(Scada *)getFirstScada {
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];   //Crashing here

    Scada *retVal = nil;

    //maybe some check before, to be sure results is not empty
    if ([results count] == 0) {
        retVal = nil;
    } else {
        retVal = [results firstObject];
    }

    return retVal;
}

+ (int)insertNewScada:(NSString *)scadaName HostName:(NSString *)scadaHostName {
    int returnValue = 0;

    Scada *newScada = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([Scada class]) inManagedObjectContext:context];

    //Configure the new scada object.
    [newScada setName:scadaName];
    [newScada setHostname:[scadaHostName uppercaseString]];

    // Save the context.
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        returnValue = -1;
    } else {
        returnValue = 1;
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

My call today are like this in `AppDelegate`:

Doesn't work:

```
Scada *scada = [Scada getFirstScada];
```

Works:

```
[Scada insertNewScada:@"tmp" HostName:@"T.E.M.P/DELETE"];
[Scada removeScada:@"T.E.M.P/DELETE"];

Scada *scada = [Scada getFirstScada];
```

The crash log (not all of it):

> Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
>
> Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) Exception Codes:
>   EXC_I386_GPFLT Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
>
> Application Specific Information: objc_msgSend() selector name:
>   fetchLimit CoreSimulator 303.8 - Device: iPhone 6s - Runtime: iOS 10.0
>   (14A345) - DeviceType: iPhone 6s
>
> Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread 0
>   libobjc.A.dylib                   0x000000010e19facb objc_msgSend + 11 1 
>   com.novotek.SmartDirect           0x000000010b1d113a +[Scada
>   getFirstScada] + 74 (Scada.m:120) 2   com.novotek.SmartDirect
>     0x000000010b1f21fd -[AppDelegate
>   application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 109 (AppDelegate.m:36) 3
>   com.apple.UIKit                   0x000000010c3f968e -[UIApplication
>   _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 290 4   com.apple.UIKit                  0x000000010c3fb013 -[UIApplication
>   _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4236 5   com.apple.UIKit                   0x000000010c4013b9 -[UIApplication
>   _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1731 6   com.apple.UIKit                   0x000000010c3fe539 -[UIApplication
>   workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188 7   com.apple.FrontBoardServices 
>     0x000000010feef76b **FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 24
>   8   com.apple.FrontBoardServices      0x000000010feef5e4 -[FBSSerialQueue
>   _performNext] + 189 9   com.apple.FrontBoardServices      0x000000010feef96d -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] +
>   45 10  com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x000000010e6cd311
>   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17 11  com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x000000010e6b259c
>   __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556 12  com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x000000010e6b1a86 __CFRunLoopRun + 918 13  com.apple.CoreFoundation 
>     0x000000010e6b1494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420 14  com.apple.UIKit
>     0x000000010c3fcdb6 -[UIApplication _run] + 434 15  com.apple.UIKit
>     0x000000010c402f34 UIApplicationMain + 159 16 
>   com.novotek.SmartDirect           0x000000010b1e6d7f main + 111
>   (main.m:16) 17  libdyld.dylib                     0x000000010f55b68d
>   start + 1
>
> Thread 1: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000010f8875e2
>   __workq_kernreturn + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x000000010f99b578 _pthread_wqthread + 1283 2
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x000000010f999341 start_wqthread + 13
>
> Thread 2:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager 0
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x000000010f887efa kevent_qos + 10 1
>   libdispatch.dylib                 0x000000010f506c3b
>   _dispatch_mgr_wait_for_event + 79 2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000010f500a85 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 248 3   libdispatch.dylib
>     0x000000010f500887 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 54
>
> Thread 3: 0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000010f999334
>   start_wqthread + 0
>
> Thread 4: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000010f8875e2
>   __workq_kernreturn + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x000000010f99b578 _pthread_wqthread + 1283 2
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x000000010f999341 start_wqthread + 13
>
> Thread 5:: com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread 0
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x000000010f880f72 mach_msg_trap + 10 1
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x000000010f8803b3 mach_msg + 55 2
>   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x000000010e6b27b4
>   **CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212 3   com.apple.CoreFoundation         0x000000010e6b1c31 __CFRunLoopRun + 1345 4   com.apple.CoreFoundation
>     0x000000010e6b1494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420 5
>
>   com.apple.Foundation              0x000000010dc6c080
>   -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 274 6   com.apple.Foundation            0x000000010dcf3a21
>   -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 78 7   com.apple.UIKit                0x000000010ce8896d -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 118 8
>
>   com.apple.Foundation              0x000000010dc7bf74 __NSThread__start**
>   + 1243 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x000000010f99b99d _pthread_body + 131 10  libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x000000010f99b91a _pthread_start + 168 11  libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x000000010f999351 thread_start + 13
>
> Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):   rax:
>   0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x000000010dff6170 
>   rdx: 0x0000000000000004   rdi: 0x00006000000cf5e0  rsi:
>   0x000000010c223983  rbp: 0x00007fff54a2e280  rsp: 0x00007fff54a2dbf8
>   r8: 0x0000000000000070   r9: 0x00006000000cf5e0  r10:
>   0xbadd7088dd4fbead  r11: 0x000000010c223983   r12: 0x00006000001ddc40 
>   r13: 0x00006000000cf5e0  r14: 0x000060000005f710  r15:
>   0x5e0081f7ad0372c5   rip: 0x000000010e19facb  rfl: 0x0000000000010202 
>   cr2: 0x000000010bfd9e18    Logical CPU:     0 Error Code:
>   0x00000000 Trap Number:     13
>
> Binary Images:
>          0x10b1cf000 -        0x10b200fff +com.novotek.SmartDirect (2.1.0 - 160906) <9C490211-3872-3C30-97F6-FDE317F5A424>
>   /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/34113BFD-BEE2-4BEF-B77E-0A7DD14B2C55/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/34D88A3E-8915-4552-AAEC-5F4D2F415983/SmartDirect.app/SmartDirect
>          0x10b237000 -        0x10b25f707 +dyld_sim (360.22) 
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib/dyld_sim
>          0x10b2a8000 -        0x10b333fff  com.apple.Security (10.0 - ???) <71DB299C-DADC-331C-A9D8-1DB136470E89>
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
>          0x10b39c000 -        0x10b746fff  com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox (1.8 - 1.8)
>   <811188B5-6E3B-30E2-986E-19C52D09BC51>
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
>          0x10b8ae000 -        0x10bee1fff  com.apple.CoreGraphics (2.0 - 1070) 
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
>          0x10bfbe000 -        0x10c295ff7 +CoreData (752.1) <38BD041F-73CC-3993-8FB5-BAE51919D9BA>
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
>          0x10c3db000 -        0x10d282ff7  com.apple.UIKit (1.0 - 1000) <8E889F15-2893-3D6E-B9DB-D2C7F3EA4CDF>
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
>          0x10dc4b000 -        0x10df31ff3  com.apple.Foundation (6.9 - 1349) 
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
>          0x10e184000 -        0x10e552eaf +libobjc.A.dylib (706) <6726AAD7-2FA9-3AEE-AAFC-8C72CAF72E80>
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib

Comment: Please include the crash log, and if you can, add an exception breakpoint to the app and tell us the line of code it is crashing on.

Comment: Added line where crash occur, and added log info.

Comment: This is **not** the crash log.

Comment: What does the fetchRequest contain? Does the context show nil?

Comment: The context is not nil, and the fetchRequest contains this: <NSFetchRequest: 0x6000002c5470> (entity: Scada; predicate: ((null)); sortDescriptors: ((null)); type: NSManagedObjectResultType; )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help.

It seems to be a static method that gets called twice which re-initialized a variable.

Found the solution while looking for the crash log, and stumbled over Zombie in xcode...